# Where has the Ubuntu One Contacts app for Android gone?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, contacts

I had problems syncing my Android 2.3.4 device with Ubuntu One Contacts cloud.
So I decided to reinstall the Android app.
But I can't find the app any more.

Where is it?
How can I sync the contacts of my Android device with the Ubuntu One Cloud?

At the moment, unfortunately, my contacts on the Android device are empty!
I am paying for this service.

Answer (score 4):

The old funambol clients were giving us and our users too many severe problems, and we discontinued the service.

From [our blog post](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=943),

> As of June 1, 2011 the current Ubuntu One contacts sync for mobile
>   will no longer be active. We’re stopping support for our current
>   service so we can focus our energy on launching a much better service
>   sooner than we could otherwise.